# No final da impressão da String sempre sai o 0p. O que é?

Tags: c

Fiz um código para aceitar somente alguns carateres lidos em um vetor e passar para outro vetor. No caso, o primeiro o usuario pode digitar o que quiser e o programa mantem somente digitos, operações matematicas (+ - / * ^) e as letras p e i. Consegui fazer tranquilamente, mas na hora de imprimir o vetor já sem os caracteres indesejados imprime sempr com um 0p no final.

```
int retira_espaco(int tamanho, char vetor[], int t, char retorno []){ //função para retirar os espaços digitados
    int i = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
        if (isdigit(vetor[i]) || vetor[i] == 'i' || vetor[i] == 'p' || vetor[i] == '+' || vetor[i] == '-' || vetor[i] == '*' || vetor[i] == '/' || vetor[i] == '^'){
        retorno[contador++] = vetor[i];
    }
}
    retorno[contador] = '\0';
    return (retorno);
}

void main() // função principal
{
int tamanho = 100;
char vetor[tamanho];
char retorno[tamanho];
printf("DIGITE A EXPRESSAO QUE DEVE SER RESOLVIDA:\n");
fgets(vetor, tamanho, stdin);
printf("%s", retira_espaco(tamanho, vetor, tamanho, retorno));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depois de resolver os erros que impediam a compilação, funcionou: http://ideone.com/mRG31j

Comment: Eu ia comentar agora, @bigown (principalmente sobre o retorno `char *` ao invés de inteiro na função). :) Vc heim, sempre mais rápido. rs

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que testar se `vetor[i]` é diferente de zero binário, porque `fgets` sempre coloca um zero binário no final do campo digitado. Caso contrário o loop segue até o final de `vetor`, e pode considerar lixo (memória não inicializada) como caracteres válidos.

```
for (i = 0; i < tamanho && vetor[i] != 0; i++)
{
    if (isdigit(vetor[i]) || vetor[i] == 'i' || vetor[i] == 'p'
       || vetor[i] == '+' || vetor[i] == '-' || vetor[i] == '*'
       || vetor[i] == '/' || vetor[i] == '^')
    {
       retorno[contador++] = vetor[i];
    }
}
```